# Masterpage Vs Themes decision dilemma

Tags: c#, asp.net, themes, master-pages

I am decision dilemma as to the requirement of a client

> I want to change the look and Layout both of the site - XXX Client

Generally this is how it should work,

- You change a theme the website is displayed with different images and Colors.
- You change a masterpage your website changes it's layout (sidebar moved to right from left - provided the layout is specified in masterpage)

I am confused as to how one would accomplish this. If i design my pages using a default masterpage then when i switch to another masterpage there is no assurance that other masterpage might have same content placeholders.

```
This would throw an exception
```

**How can i implement multiple masterpages Intelligently without creating 2 pages each for the respective masterpage ?**

#### Edit

dilemma is caused by other colleague implementing his own ideas into pages developed by him, He over popups to display forms  on sidebar link clicks mine directs to separate pages.

Comment: you are over-thinking this. you should use the same masterpage, and load a diffrent css, where the sidebar has 'float:right' instead no float or 'float:left'

Comment: @Dementic Please view **Edit** i forgot to mention another problem. One of colleague has developed his part where the sidebar items on click show form as popup's. The pages developed my me directs the clicks to separate page.

Comment: so your college should calculate where the sidebar is. and pop it up relatively to it.

Comment: @Dementic arrhhh People you have to put up with in Work. I guess world is ever learning library

Comment: Sorry mate, but if your friend is not checking if the sidebar exists, or where it is, he's not doing he's job. think about it this way, the city moves a bus stop 200 meters further the road, will your friend keep waiting at the old bus stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this in CSS without changes to masterpages or themes.  That way you will guarantee that the content placeholders will be unchanged.

Change your images to be set from CSS (something like):

`.imageFromCss { background:url("../images/myimage.png");`}

And CSS can move sidebars from left to right:

```
.sidebar {display:inline; float:right;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change dynamicly the masterpage on PreIint.

```
    Select Case iForum
        Case 6 '41 
            MasterPageFile = "/Children/Forum.master"
        Case Else

            MasterPageFile = "/Ezra/Forum.master"
    End Select
```

(I know that I can write better example)

Now, Create a `BaseMaster` class, with your variables, functions, etc, and inherit the website MasterPage from this class.

Now add to the top of page:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="ForumMaster"%>
```

And now just use `Master.YourFunction()`. It will work with all MasterPages.

Good Luck !

Comment: Even due this will work, it is overkill for what the OP needs. yom tov ;)